# Opening Word document with long path using "\\?\" prefix results in Nothing

Tags: vba, ms-word, path

I am opening a Word document in with a file path longer than 255 characters:

```
Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("\\?\" & strFilePath)
```

In order to avoid the problem with long paths, I am trying to use the `"\\?\"` prefix which is supposed to prevent the problem: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation)

When I do this, `oDoc` is set to `Nothing`.  Why is this happening?  How can I open a document with a long path using the `"\\?\"` prefix?

Comment: What Operating System involved?

Comment: You need to use 'set' when assigning a value to an object variable. E.g. Set oDoc =.....

Comment: @freeflow sorry, corrected that typo. The question still stands.

Comment: @FaneDuru Win 7

Comment: Bad luck... Your problem could be solved in Win 10 in a way I've just described in an answer... But, why staying to Win 7?

Comment: @FaneDuru I am stuck with Win 7 at the workplace

Comment: It maybe will sound stupid, but I would try to insert the prefix in strFilePath, or even (try) writing it all, prefix included (at least, for testing)... I am afraid that VBA may consider the path expressed in this way like a relative path and the prefix does not work for such a case...

Comment: Have you confirmed a) that the file in strFilePath actually exists.  b) that the path you get for the file from Explorer plus filename matches the value in strFilePath.

Comment: @freeflow Yes it definitely exists. It is something to do with the prefix. It is causing the Open function to malfunction.

Comment: @FaneDuru I have tried adding the prefix to strFilePath in a previous statement and it makes no difference.

Comment: Did you try my second suggestion from my answer? To share the folder in discussion and map it as network drive...?

Comment: It looks VBA simple does not accept such a prefix. It is not the only application which behaves in this way...

Comment: You don't show how you arrive at the variable strFilePath. Given the issues you are facing I might try using a file system object and the BuildPath method to see if I get a valid long filename that is acceptable to VBA.

Comment: @freeflow I was using File.Path, but I'm now using File.ShortPath which has solved the problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

If your OS is Windows 10, you can solve your problem by just modifying a Registry Key from 0 to 1. You firstly check if the key in discussion exists and it has the default value (0):

```
Debug.Print CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled")
```

If it returns 0 (zero) in Immediate Window, the key exists and must be changed to 1. After that, **you can use your existing (long) path** which may exceed 255 characters.

If no Windows 10, I would suggest you to share the folder in discussion and map it. Network - Your computer - Right click on the folder and choose 'Map network drive`...